# OAuth on Slack Entreprise

Tags: oauth-2.0, slack

I try to set up a bot on a Slack Entreprise account but I keep getting a 
**scope_not_allowed_on_entreprise**

I've tried with the following scopes

- **identity.basic**
- **identity.email**
- **identity.team**
- **identity.avatar**

I've looked into the documentation 
https://api.slack.com/scopes and https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth
but there's no specific mentions of an Entreprise specific quirk or rules.

I tried removing the scope in the url, but it says scope cannot be blank.

Any idea where I could find some documentation or information on that ?

Thanks

Comment: please add the scopes that are not working to your question. Also, you can try with the generic scopes `bot` and/or `command` if your approach works at all.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I've updated with the scopes, thanks.